# Update Missing Title, Alt Text,Description for Images

Tags: media-library, pipelines

We are using `Sitecore 8.2 Update 2` and it has a lot of images which has missing Title, ALt text and Description for Images. We performed below action

- Wrote a Pipeline which inherits from Render field and updated issing Title, ALt text and Description for Images.

However, this leading to a lot of performance issues

Is somebody aware of Pipeline which I can use for CD which updates all the missing elements on the page at once.  I want to avoid multiple hits on Pipeline

Comment: Why not update the images missing alt text, description and title in Sitecore? You can use a powershell script to update all of them. Hence you won’t need a pipeline to execute on the front end to add the missing data

Comment: The client wants to update only on CD side only and not from CMS

Comment: From where the images takes the value for the Title, Description and alt text?

Comment: These values are taken from Image name itself

Comment: OK. This is why I am suggesting to update the image items where the title, description and alt text is missing in the CMS. Since the name of the image won't change, when the image will render on the Front end, it will reads the data directly from the image hence you will not require to update it on the fly during rendering time. Maybe I am missing what's the main requirement

Comment: 1. Create a small JS script to  get all IMAGE elements and update the title , alt for the same element. This is Quick work around  2. call the pipeline code in a JOB that executes only once ( configurable) to update the image attributes. Here use content search manager classes.

Comment: Did the client explain why they don't want to update the original image fields in the CMS? Perhaps the community would benefit from this understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As others are saying SPE and Cognitive Services is a great approach for this I've blogged about a solution for how to do this here:

http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/auto-setting-alt-text-existing-new-images-in-sitecore-with-cognitive-services/

It handles setting alt text for both new and existing images by analysing the image using Cognitive Services and setting the alt text based on the results.

The SPE script for existing images is here: https://gist.github.com/fluxdigital/2b6041c579770f891df1a0da43cdcd63

The module to handle adding alt text for new images (or when updating images) is here: https://github.com/fluxdigital/AutoAltTags (a tweaked version of Tom Dudfields module)

Both these solutions require setting the alt text field of the image on the CM (which I know you've mentioned isn't what you wanted) but if you want to avoid hitting a pipeline on the CD server each time that is likely the best way to achieve this. We will need more info on why you can't use the alt text field of the image on the CM if we are to suggest alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I will also suggest you to create a SPE script to update the existing images in Sitecore. You can simply integrate Cognitive Services for this in your script and after that can use the same for the upload-image. Also, there are some modules available in the marketplace. but if you don't want to do this than you don't need to modify any pipeline.
Sitecore supports parameter in render field where you can pass "Title, Alt and Description".

```
 @Html.Sitecore().Field("ImageField",YourItem, new { title = "YourTitle",alt="YourAlt", description="YourDescription" })
```

I hope this will help you.