# Is there a way to enable 'alt text' for multiple images using Batch upload

Tags: powershell

When uploading multiple images using `Batch upload`, there is no ability to add `alt text` at once. Is there a way to allow/add distance `alt text` to multiple images during upload without having to open and edit each item? Can we achieve this using SPE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Missing Title, Alt Text,Description for Images](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20805/update-missing-title-alt-text-description-for-images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simpler Way:**

You can put `$name` to the alt field in the standard value of an image `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Image/__Standard Values`. This way if content authors forget to fill the alt field during upload or in the case of batch upload, it is pre-filled with the file name.

**Sitecore Powershell way:**

The above method will work for future uploads but if you want to populate the alt tags for already media files, you can run below powershell script:

```
$mediaItemContainer = Get-Item "master:/sitecore/media library/MyImages"
    $items = $mediaItemContainer.Axes.GetDescendants() | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder -and $_.Fields["Alt"] -ne $null } | Initialize-Item
    
foreach($item in $items) {
        if(-not($item."Alt")) {
           $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
           $item.Fields["Alt"].Value = $item.Name
           $item.Editing.EndEdit() }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue. But client is looking for the classic upload which we used to have earlier.

Comment: See this thread to move to classic upload in media library : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8880/can-i-force-the-old-upload-file-interface-instead-of-the-new-batch-upload-when-u

Comment: Hi Raman, I followed this thread and tried setting up the sc_fv cookie value to 9.0.0. Even tried to delete them. I created a custom pipeline to do the same. But this doesn't seem to work. Any guidance would be helpful